# Same STL files with different compilers

Tags: c++, stl

There are two binary files obtained from the same source file: one compiled with clang++-3.6 and the other one with g++-4.8. In a call to a function from the stl (std::unique, in particular) gdb brings me to the same file: /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h.

I expected that the implementations would be different for each compiler though. Do clang and gcc share parts of their C++ implementations?

Comment: Depends on how you use them. They use the headers and the library they are told to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I expected that the implementations would be different for each compiler though. Do clang and gcc share parts of their C++ implementations?

It's not that they share the same C++ implementations, it is rather that both compilers link with the same standard c++ library by default on your system.

I presume you are on linux, almost all programs installed from package manager link against libstdc++ (provided by g++).

By default, even when compiling with clang++, libstdc++ is used, so when you include iostream for example, it uses the one from /usr/include/c++/4.8.

If you want to link against llvm c++ library, you need to install the "libc++-dev" package *(name may vary depending on your distro)* and compile using: **-stdlib=libc++** (instead of the default: -stdlib=libstdc++).

**example:**

test.cpp:

```
    #include <iostream>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        std::cout << "Hello World!!!\n";

        return 0;
    }
```

compiling using:

```
   $ clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -o test test.cpp
```

will use the header from /usr/include/c++/v1 (from llvm)

but compiling using:

```
    $ clang++ -stdlib=libstdc++ -o test test.cpp

# or (assuming the default on your system is libstdc++)

    $ clang++ -o test test.cpp
```

will use header from /usr/include/c++/4.8 (from g++)

Comment: Great answer. It's a shame that the `gcc` argument names are so terrible. Why can't we have `-stdlib=clang`?

Comment: @Elliott clang is not part of the gcc project and clang is only one piece of the llvm compiler chain and it is not the standard library portion of it. However both clang++ and g++ try to accept the same flags and argument names where they overlap in function. Some of them are decades old and integrated into to so many build systems and tools that changing them would be extremely disruptive for a very minor superficial benefits.